# Android. Фильтрация GPS данных, какую погрешность считать за норму?

Tags: android, gps

Хотел найти пример приложения с удачного реализованным фильтром GPS-данных, скачал два популярных трекера MyTracks, Open GPS Tracker. Первый разработали сами гугловцы. 
Запускаю, оба трекера выписывают кренделя и насчитывают киллометры, когда телефон лежит на месте(за 20 минут первое приложение насчитало 2.5км второе 1.9км, третье без фильтров 4.5км). Сервис Traccar на демо сервере без доп настроек 3.7 км. Да телефон дешовый и GPS тоже, но все равно:

1. Все на самом деле так плохо? Считать эту погрешность нормой или у
   разработчиков были руки кривые?
2. При движении на авто какую погрешность считать нормой?

P.S. Все очень относительно, но может найдется человек, который собаку съел на этом деле и определился с нормами в построении маршрутов.

Answer (score 4):

1. У разработчиков руки нормально. Только все телефоны по разному определяют координаты. И еще это зависит от погоды, здании где вы сидите и т.п. Так что если программа работает на улице нормально, это норма.
2. Если на авто берите каждые 200 метров. Так лучше. И еще попробуйте фиксировать координаты при:

   - каждые 200 метров
   - если угол поворота авто больше 15 С
   - если не движется фиксация каждую минуту.

---

еще попробуйте программу от https://www.traccar.org/

Traccar (Server):

```
git clone https://github.com/tananaev/traccar.git
```

Traccar Client for Android:

```
git clone https://github.com/tananaev/traccar-client-android.git
```

Traccar Client for iOS:

```
https://github.com/tananaev/traccar-client-ios.git
```

Comment: Может быть я не прав, но насколько я понял Traccar в плане построения маршрутов очень примитивная программа, фильтрации GPS данных нет. На Android-овском клиенте её вообще нет, а на сервере примитивная фильтрация происходит на уровне выкидывания дублей, нуливых координат и т.д. но не на уровне усреднения координат (фильтр Калмана, фильтр Альфа-бетта). А уж про отслеживания поворотов там и речи не идет. Мне кажется в пример её нельзя ставить.

Comment: @Gennady это один из примеров. Там есть фильтрация по погрешности, GPS и Network. Но мои советы были не по Traccar, а по практике в трекерах.

Comment: А угол поворота авто как высчитывают?

Comment: @Gennady по последним 3 точкам. 2 первые зафиксированные, 3я ишется, тоесть real-time точку берете и проверяете. Если совпадает, фиксируете

Comment: Столько ньюансов, об этом можно где-нибудь почитать?

Comment: @Gennady есть еще такие вещи как количество спутников, уровень сигнала GSM и другие, которые тоже можно для аналитики сипользовать